# Does TCP kills dead idle connection after keepalive packet is sent

Tags: tcp, tcp-keepalive

My understandings for TCP keepalive:

This keepalive does not really "keeping connection alive". Instead, "detectAlive" may be a more proper word: Tcp levels exchange heartbeat packet to detect whether an idle conneciton dead or alive.

Here are my questions:

1. After TCP knows that the connection is dead, does the TCP level automatically closes the connection?
2. After TCP knows that the connection is dead, how does application level know that infomation? By knowing that infomation it thus close the socket and release the resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After TCP knows that the connection is dead, does the TCP level automatically closes the connection?

TCP is a protocol. It "knows" nothing. The specific implementation in the OS though will detect if the TCP connection can no longer exchange data with or without payload (i.e. keep alive) and will close the **local** state of the connection. It will not do the normal TCP connection close which involves sending FIN etc, because it can be assumed that the connection is broken.

> After TCP knows that the connection is dead, how does application level know that information? By knowing that infomation it thus close the socket and release the resource

This depends on the application. The application needs to somehow monitor the state of the socket, i.e. doing a write, read, select or similar. These functions will then no longer block and the broken state of the connection can be determined for example based on error code in read/write or similar. If the application instead does not care about the socket for some time it will only realize the problem once it starts caring again.